# Any way to fire a VB.NET button from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a menu on my aspx page which looks beautiful. It's exactly what I need (found it [here](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/#)).

Problem that I have is this: I need (somehow) to kick off a button control from the javascript. I realize that in the example, the menu items are simply href links, but I'm wondering how I could possibly do a postback and kick off my Button1_OnClick event.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

Please note that Button1 is an ASP button, with server-side VB.NET code behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click()` method of any `<a>` element simulates a click.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The problem is that he doesn't know how to refer to the button itself from ASP.NET. This is because ASP.NET buttons are on the server-side, and the client-side doesn't reflect it precisely the same.

Comment: @Helgi The postback will "know" the button.

Comment: @pst: He still needs to identify the button itself from JavaScript. There is no postback until the button is clicked, and the OP is stuck on how to click it from JavaScript.

Comment: Here's what I have: <a onclick="PrintBatchJS">Print</a>

Comment: function PrintBatchJS()
{   document.getElementById("<%= PrintBatch.ClientID %>").click();}

Comment: @Helgi: Not necessarily. It can be identified by index, or by relations... and that's made almost impossibly easy using jQuery. Otherwise, it's just the usual easy.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need something like

```
 __doPostBack(*Button1's clientId*,"OnClick") ;
```

Comment: I would recommend using the ASP.NET functions to generate the `__doPostBack` code. However, this should work on all browsers (with JavaScript).

Comment: That is, use `Page.ClientScript` to get a [`ClientScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) and use `GetPostBackEventReference` to generate the `__doPostBack` stuff. +1 For not using `click()`.

Answer (score 1):

Button1 will have a property called "ClientID". You can echo that out to the HTML code to get the object by `document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>")`, and from there you only have to invoke the click like normally.

So:

```
document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click();
```

As noted by a commentator, the .click() method won't work in all browsers. Here is one another way to click a button in JavaScript (should also work with links):

```
// Where 'button' is the value of the document.getElementById() function:
if (button.dispatchEvent) {
    var e = document.createEvent(“MouseEvents”);
    e.initEvent(“click”, true, true);
    button.dispatchEvent(e);
}
else {
    button.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my response accordingly.

Comment: Can't seem to find the 'ClientID' for my button. It's a standard ASP button, with the ID set to 'PrintBatch'. Looks like this: <asp:Button ID="PrintBatch" runat="server" Height="21px" Text="Print Batch" 
                        Width="102px" BackColor="#6699FF" BorderStyle="Double" />

Comment: So I guess I'm searching for getElementByID("<%= PrintBatch.? %>")

Comment: @Jason ClientID is a property of an ASP.NET Control -- it is some funny long string which equates to the *actual* ID in the DOM, which is not what the "ID" of the ASP.NET control is set to! (I think ASP.NET 4 allows this to be changed? In any case... the control must also be *rendered* -- e.g. Visible -- for the ClientID to be of use.)

Comment: Tried the following, but no luck: function PrintBatchJS()
{   document.getElementById("<%= PrintBatch.ClientID %>").click();}

Comment: <a onclick="PrintBatchJS">Print</a>

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `<a />` links, LinkButtons. You could alternativly keep your `<a />` links and put `runat="server"` on them and that would do it without having to fire a separate button click.